# Google Conversion Tracking for iOS linker error for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, linker-errors, google-ads-api, armv7, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to add the Google Conversion Tracking for iOS feature to my iPhone app.
The app's base SDK is iOS6
the app's valid architectures is armv7, armv7s
the app's iOS deployment targer is 4.3
I'm using the latest xcode 4.5.2 and OSX 10.8.2

The app is in appstore and is ok for iPhone 3-4-5

When I try to add the Google Conversion Tracking for iOS following this link: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/conversion-tracking

I have this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libGoogleConversionTracking.a(PingUtil.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: OK, the problem was that I didn't include the AdSupport.framework This info is not present in the documentation but I found it in a image inside the doc....

Comment: Or `#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>`

Comment: importing doesnt remove my error :(

Answer (score 5):

> The SDK library references the iOS AdSupport development framework
>   which may not already be part of your project. It can be resolved by
>   including AdSupport.Framework.
>
> To adding the Framework, just follow the steps below. Select the
>   project file at the top. Open the Link Binary With Libraries drop-down
>   under the Build Phases tab.  Add the framework from the iOS SDK using
>   the + button.

Comment: Careful with that AdSupport library; including it in your project, and not using it, seems to trigger something during the Apple approval process. Ref: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=387

Comment: Does anyone know if there is still a aproblem with the apple review process and including the AdSupport framework for this purpose?